# Debugging IE7 ajax loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently trying to debug some weird error that occur only in IE7.

The errors repported by IE are pointing to an empty line, or sometime the line 1. I think some of the errors could occur on a page that is loaded by AJAX.
The first error is:

```
Line: 1
Character: 181
Code: 0
Error Message: 'null' is null or not an object
URL: http://192.168.1.103/repositories/asdasd/public_html/admin/module/admin/News/Mod?id=23
```

The page source is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Prendre en charge la soumission des formulaire. Les traiter en AJAX par défaut.
$("#form_add-image").bind("submit", function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#form_add-image").attr("action"),
        type: $("#form_add-image").attr("method"),
        data: $("#form_add-image").serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){

            //Remplacer le contenu
            manualLightboxContent(data, {'width': 1000, 'zIndex': 500000}, "#dialog_imagesZone");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
<div id="main" class="s_formulaires outlined">
<form id="form_add-image" action="/repositories/asdasd/public_html/admin/moduleAJAX/admin/Media/chain-execute/add-image" method="post">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#crop_box').Jcrop({
        setSelect: [ 1380, 0, 1080, 1080],
        aspectRatio: 1,
        bgOpacity: 0.5,
        boxWidth: 640,
        boxHeight: 480,
        onChange: showCoords,
        onSelect: showCoords
    });

    $('#crop_button').button();

    function showCoords(c){
        $('#crop_left').val(c.x);
        $('#crop_top').val(c.y);
        $('#crop_right').val(c.x2);
        $('#crop_bottom').val(c.y2);
        $('#crop_width').val(c.w);
        $('#crop_height').val(c.h);
    };
});
</script>

<h2>Recadrer l'image</h2>
<div style="margin:10px;">
<img src="http://192.168.1.103/repositories/asdasd/public_html/media/module_news/files/23-226-Capture-2.png" id="crop_box" />
</div>
Déplacez la sélection pour choisir la zone à conserver<br /><br />

<div style="display:none;">
<label>left <input type="text" name="crop_left" id="crop_left" size="4"></label>
<label>top <input type="text" name="crop_top" id="crop_top" size="4"></label>
<label>right <input type="text" name="crop_right" id="crop_right" size="4"></label>
<label>bottom <input type="text" name="crop_bottom" id="crop_bottom" size="4"></label>
<label>width <input type="text" name="crop_width" id="crop_width" size="4"></label>
<label>height <input type="text" name="crop_height" id="crop_height" size="4"></label>
</div>

<button id="crop_button">Accepter la sélection</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The page is a lightbox, so it use the script loaded from the main page. ( In this case: JQuery & JCrop )

Do you have an idea to help me debugging this ... because the errors are not very verbose.

Comment: Download IE8, has an IE7 mode. You can use the debugger in the browser to debug the problem.

Comment: That's what we're doing right now. But the error appear to be inside a method called  __flash__addCallback, that an internal JS method of the browser. I'm trying to figure out a way of finding the execution path that lead to that point.

Comment: I just found an answer to my specific bug (in the following link), and posted a solution. But still, I'd like to have more verbose with IE ! http://passion4code.com/2010/12/10/jquery-ie-and-__flash__addcallback/#comment-388

And yes, it has nothing to do with the examples I posted... I would have searched for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185) gives decent error messages, but is hard to configure properly on a modern operating system.